# apache server 8080 port conflict with cherrypy

Tags: apache, cherrypy

I heard about cherrypy and out of curiosity tried to run this script.

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

to run this i needed to stop my apache which was already running.
after running this for the first time i got the "Hello World" output but now when i am trying to access my localhost:8080 the browser goes into an indefinite long loading state i think their is some conflict between cherrypy and apache or something help me out plz 
what to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define what port CherryPy should listen to.

By issuing **cherrypy.config.update()** before **cherrypy.quickstart()**, you can change what port the server listens to. In my example it's 7077.

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 7077})
```

For more information about the configuration of CherryPy, there's [this documentation](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/concepts/config.html).